# Cheletropic carbene addition to ethene under Woodward-Hoffmann rules

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory

Woodward and Hoffmann state in their seminal paper [1], that a ground-state pericyclic reaction is thermally allowed when $p+q=\textrm{odd}$, with $p=(4n)_{antara}$ and $q = (4m+2)_{supra}$. When I look at a cheletropic carbene addition to an ethene (see Figure, from [2]), this rule gets a bit shady for me.

[image: Cheletropic Carbene insertion]

Essentially, there are two ways to look at it:
1) The HOMO is the two-electron sp2 orbital on the carbene and the LUMO the the $\pi^*$ LUMO on the olefin.
2) The HOMO is the $\pi$ orbital on the olefin and the LUMO the pz orbital on the carbene.

Case 1) results in a $p=1$ from the sp2 and $q=1$ from the $\pi^*$, so $p+q=\textrm{even}$. The same can be verified for case 2). How can this be, since these kinds of insertion are usually thermally allowed? Even when I would add together both situations, I'd get an even number. Does the Woodward-Hoffmann system work here or am I missing something?

[1] http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/anie.196907811/abstract 
[2] http://chemistry.caltech.edu/courses/ch242/H1.pdf

Comment: Carbene additions are a little finicky under Woodward-Hoffmann rules - if you have library access, I would refer you to Ian Fleming's [*Pericyclic Reactions*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Pericyclic-Reactions-Oxford-Chemistry-Primers/dp/0198503075), pp 47-48. He also has lots to say in his other text [*Molecular Orbitals and Organic Chemical Reactions*](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470746580.html) - there is a huge section on W-H rules and the part on carbenes begins at p281 of the Reference Edition.

Comment: Molecular Orbitals and Organic Chemical Reactions is indeed an excellent suggestion. This [https://www.scripps.edu/baran/images/grpmtgpdf/Martinez_13.pdf] PDF from a Baran group meeting might also be useful, it discusses the same kind of cheloptropic additions you're interested in